# Develop Euclidean distance in for loop in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the Euclidean distance between two columns in data frames. Compare the first row with the rest rows to get the distance.

This is my code so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("Data_HW1.csv")

dist = []
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    dist = ((data.iloc[0, 0] - data.iloc[i, 0]) ** 2 + (data.iloc[0, 1] - data.iloc[1, i]) ** 2)
    print((dist) ** (1 / 2))
```

It gives me list error index out of range. I am also trying to get a new column with the new distance values between the first row and the rest of them.

Comment: The picture of the data frame can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVMIA.jpg

Comment: I think the problem lies in `data.iloc[1,i]` which should have been `data.iloc[i,1]`. Btw, it's a practice here to post your data in text format so people can copy and paste to test code that they would like to propose to you.